# Concurrency issue between waiting for a process and reading the stream?

Tags: java, multithreading, outputstream, executorservice, processbuilder

I use a `ProcessBuilder` to run processes. I handle Input/Output streams by submitting the corresponding runnables handling them in a thread pool (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`).
I get the result but every now and then I don't get anything.
For instance if I do: `cmd \C dir` to the process builder I get the results of `dir` back but sometimes I don't get anything (despite that the result seems to comeback from the runnable that handles the `process.getInputStream`).
How can I debug this? It shows up intermitently.
With the same code I did not have any problem when I did `new Thread(runnable).start()`. It started to happen after I switched to a thread pool.

**Update:**
I think I found something:
I do the following in the `Runnable`:

```
 try {  
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            pw.println(line);  
                sb.append(line);   
    }  
    System.out.println("Finished reading "+sb.length());  
} catch (IOException e) {             
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
finally{  
   pw.flush();     
  try{
    isr.close();  
  }catch(Exception e){}  
}
```

In the cases that does not work it prints `Finished reading 521`. But I try to get the result via the `pw` and not `sb`.
`pw` is PrintWriter pw = PrintWriter(outputStream);` which I pass in the runnable

**Update 2:**
It seems that:`status = process.waitFor();` returns earlier **before** the runnable that handled the inputstream finishes. How can this happen?
I read in the javadoc:
`the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits`. So does that mean that I could return *before* consuming the I/O streams?

**Update 3:**
Seems to be the same issue here in [Ruby](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3275) 
I.e. **there is some race condition between the process ending and consuming the output**

Comment: If a process calls another process the first process might return prematurely - normal behaviour.

Comment: This not about premature returning.It is about returning *before* the output streams has been consumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. stdio between processes is buffered (usually 4KB buffers). Process A write into the buffer and exist. Process B has two threads; one waits for the end of A and the other reads the output from A. There is no way to be sure which thread executes first.

So it's possible (even likely when there is a lot of output) that `process.waitFor();` returns before all buffered output has been read.

Note that flushing doesn't help here because it just makes sure that A has *written* everything. There is no way to "force" B to read the data in a similar way.

Therefore, you should remember the exit status and consider the process as "fully terminated" only when you read EOF from the input stream.

**EDIT** One solution would be to move the `waitFor()` into the stream gobbler and convert the gobbler into a `Callable` which you could then submit to the executor and use the `Future` API ([example](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6)) to get the result(s).

Comment: So how should I modify my code to handle that?I just do `waitFor` now and the code in my stream reader is posted

Comment: Call `waitFor` and then `join()` on the thread which contains the stream handler. Or have the stream handler call `waitFor()` outside of the `while()` loop to have both in the same place.

Comment: 1)Stream handler is submitted to an executor.How can I `join`?2)How can the stream handler call `waitFor`?The result is supposed to be passed to the thread waiting for the process to finish

Comment: You will have to use a different strategy. For example, give the stream handler a handle to an instance which can process the result instead of waiting. Or push the results into a queue and have a thread wait for work in this queue.

Comment: What about converting `Runnable` to `Callable` and do `get` for each stream gobler?